# How to serve a static file without causing a disk read?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

[`res.sendFile`](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.sendFile) is the recommended way to send a static file using [express](/questions/tagged/express). However, from what I can tell, `res.sendFile` is reading file from the disk on every request, e.g.

```
router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile('./guest.js');
});
```

Accessing `/` will make a disk read on every request.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that [express](/questions/tagged/express) does indeed read on every request (it is hard to confirm, because it could be using a clever cache that utilises [`fs.watch`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/fs.html#fs_fs_watch_filename_options_listener) or [`fs.stat`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_stat_path_callback) to asses whether to read a new file), then a simple solution is to get the file's content into a variable and serve it using [`res.rend`](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.send), e.g.

```
const guestScript = fs.readFileSync('./guest.js', 'utf-8');

router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res
        .set('Content-Type', 'application/javascript')
        .send(guestScript);
});
```

Comment: `res.sendFile` [does read](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/f3d99a4fdbe1531ea609e92c4d4ae6c269d78c7a/lib/response.js#L385-L420) the file on every invocation.